# How to set php variable as value of input text html

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a below code which has a input text box and its value I want to set is php variable. Below is the code:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
            Select file: <input name="userfile" type="file"/>

            <input type="text" name="filename" value=<?php echo $filename; ?> />

            <input type="submit" value="Send File" multiple/>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now the above code is working fine and it does what is written in `upload.php`. But for some reason, inside the input type text box, there is `<br` in it. I am not able to make it clear. Also it says undefined variable `filename`. Below is the screenshot of the webpage:

[image]

Can anyone please help in why it says `filename` undefined variable and why `<br` is shown on input type text box. I have tried below approach but nothing worked:

`<input type="text" name="filename" value="<?php echo $filename; ?>" />`

`<input type="text" name="filename" value='<?php echo $filename; ?>' />`

[image]

Comment: $filename isn't defined in script. Initialize it prior to using it.

Comment: I have defined it as `$filename = "";` but doesnt worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just becuase of you are not getting `$filename` from php.

```
<?php $file = isset($filename) ? $filename : ''; ?> //if value doesn't exist it'll take '' value.
<input type="text" name="filename" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
```

Comment: No, its not working. I have attached a screenshot of its response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly set up variable value first. What you have done is not assignation, it is not in PHP tags. This is correct:

```
<?php $file = isset($filename) ? $filename : ''; ?>
<input type="text" name="filename" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
```